# captured screen video from ADB screenrecord results in a black screen

Tags: android, shell, adb

I'm using a Droid Maxx with v4.4.4 Android.  I'm trying to do:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/myvideo.mp4
```

and I am able to capture a video, which shows the desktop fine, but my app, results in a black screen showing.  I tested with facebook, which records just fine.

with verbose on, I get this as part of the shell:

```
Main display is 720x1280 @60.00fps (orientation=0)
Configuring recorder for 720x1280 video at 4.00Mbps
Content area is 720x1280 at offset x=0 y=0
```

Example recorded video shown here: http://youtu.be/ZeKhTzRpRns

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you aren't setting `FLAG_SECURE`:

> the user may see a blank region on the screen instead of the contents of secure surfaces or protected buffers.

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#FLAG_SECURE